# Action<T> equivalent for properties

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, delegates

I have a class that instantiates two classes which implement interfaces.  I want one class to notify another class that something is OK. I could do it with an Action and then use private variables in the class but wondered if there was a direct way of doing it with properties so that when a property's value changes it updates a property on another class.

For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public ILogger Logger {get;set;}
  public ILogic Logic {get;set;}

  private Form MyWinform;

  public void Setup()
  {
    MyWinform = new MyWinform();
    MyWinform.StartBatch += Logger.CreateFile; //Create file when user presses start

    //How can I set a property on ILogic to be AllOk once ILogger says so??

    //I could use an Action so that once all is ok I call IDecidedAlOK in ILogger which
    //can then assign a private bool variable inside the class

    Logic.ItsOKMethodSoSetVariableToTrue = Logger.IDecidedAllOKMethod;

  }

  public void DataIn(string Value)
  {
     Logic.DataIn(Value);
  }

  public void CreateInstances()
  {
     Logger = new FileLogger();
     Logic = new MyLogic();
  }

}

public class MyLogic : ILogic
{
   public void DataIn(string Value)
  {
     //I want to check that all is ok before I do anything

     //if (!AllOK) 
     //return;

     //Do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you own the ILogger class, I mean, can you make changes to it?

Comment: Can `ILogger` expose an `AllOK` event that `ILogic` can subscribe to?

Comment: @mellamokb Good idea, I just wondered if there was a direct way of doing it with properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event

Comment: I was trying to avoid this but seems to be a popular approach. Think I will go with a custom event though

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it might be a bit more conventional to have your ILogger interface expose something like a "FileCreated" or "Ready" event, and allow your application to handle that event in order to update the ILogic object (or do whatever else is necessary).

EDIT: my apologies, after re-reading the question, I think I misunderstood what you were asking for.

There isn't any "natural" object that does exactly what you're asking, but you could create an anonymous delegate (or lambda expression) for this purpose:

```
Action<bool> loggerResult = (value) => Logic.ItsOKMethodSoSetVariableToTrue = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

A property internally consists of two private methods, a get_XXX and a set_XXX, so unless you want to fetch the MethodInfo of those methods and invoke them (which are again methods) you have no choice but to implement a method calling approach.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to event (`INotifyPropertyChanged` or some custom one) is OK, so is the method to pass a lambda-setter, but in some cases it might be more convinient to use a shared context object (much like the shared memory concept):

```
class ConversationContext
{
   public bool EverythingIsOK { get; set;}
}
```

This object is passed to all interested objects (`ILogic` and `ILogger`) and they operate directly on it, instead of some internal properties. If change notifications are required, Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on it.

One positive aspect of this approach is that you won't get tangled in repeatedly firing events triggering other events and so on. A single object will hold the current state and no recurrent updates are needed.

Again, this is just one of many options.